# Django: Getting the value of an ordered queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model,

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.FloatField()
```

I am ordering Book objects dynamically based on a category, but I want to get the corresponding value as well. For example, when they are sorted I want to show corresponding prices as well.

Doing:

```
Book.objects.order_by('price').values()
```

and in template

```
Book: {{ book }} - Price: {{ book.value.2 }}
```

works fine. However, I want to chose which field will be sortable during runtime, for example if I want to order by pages, I need to pass `book.value.1`. So, the view should pass the field that is sorted. Something like below would solve my problem:

```
{{ book.{{ sortField }} }}
```

Django gives an error. how can I solve this? How can I pass the field so that I can use the corresponding value?

Comment: Why don't you pass a parameter to your ListView and override the queryset method to sort by?

Comment: you mean I get the variables from url, and render as listview? `url(r'^list/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Book.objects.order_by(pk))`, well this gives error saying: pk is not defined.

Comment: No, in your ListView's get method you get the parameter, `order_by = request.GET.get('order_by')`

Comment: well I have been already doing that the way you just said. There is no problem with making sort field variable. I m wondering how I get the value. Lets say I sort on some field like ordered=Books.objects.order_by(field) then   how can I know on which field it is ordered?  Because queryset gives me a dictionary, with {'book1':'price','pages','rating'}, from template's perspective I cannot understand how it will understand on which field it is sorted. When I pass field value from view to template, it knows, but then I must write all these if-else statements for each case,my model has a lot flds

Answer (score 2):

A simplified example:

**template**

```
<span>Currently ordering by {{ order_by }}</span>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?order_by=price">price</a></li>
    <li><a href="?order_by=pages">pages</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <li><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**views.py**

```
class FooListView(ListView):
    allow_ordering_on = ['pk', 'pages', 'price']  # restrictions
    order_by = 'pk'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', self.order_by)

        if order_by in self.allow_ordering_on:
            self.order_by = order_by
            self.object_list = self.model.objects.all().order_by('whatever')
            if not allow_empty and len(self.object_list) == 0:
                raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                              % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})
            context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list)
            return self.render_to_response(context)

        else:
            return super(FooListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FooListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['order_by'] = self.order_by
        return context
```

You can override `get_context_data` to add a variable for marking current field ordering.

Comment: +1 for the effort, and I admit my question is not clear enough, but this is not really what I was asking. what the above view will return? Only books or [{books},{pages},{prices}] ? I see your edit now,  can I use get_context_data in the template?

Comment: No it returns a template, `foo_list.html`, with context data, for starters `object_list` sorted by the given param. You can append to context variables by overriding get_context_data

Answer (score 0):

On shell:

```
books = Book.objects.order_by('price').values()
book = books[0]
print book['price']
```

So in the template you should be able to loop over books and access the fields:

```
{% for book in books %}    
    {{ book.price }}
{% endfor %}
```